# Why in the world is my Chrome lagging?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

I'm using my MSI GE60 2OE-202XPL laptop for some time:

- i5-4200M
- 8GB DDR3
- nVidia GeForce GTX 765M
- full HD screen
- additional full HD screen connected via HDMI
- SSD disk Plextor-256M6M
- Windows 8.1 installed on SSD, BIOS in UEFI mode
- avast is installed and according to this my PC is not infected by some malware/viruses/whatever

I believe this is the fastest I can do, as I'm not running out of RAM, my CPU is fairly good and my graphic card is probably one of the best for mobile PCs. So, why does my Google Chrome is lagging? What I mean - when I type something it takes few seconds to show what I just typed. Opening new tab also takes a few seconds.
Have you ever encountered such problems? Is there something I can do?
Already tried:

- Turning off "predict network activity to boost page loading screen" (or something like that, I don't use English localed Chrome) - nothing happened

Comment: try again with a new clean profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After so much of research, I figured out that there were some adwares which were eating the resources. You can check what is going on with Chrome's Task Manager.

Delete any such useless programs from chrome. It can be extensions or installed programs on your machine. Try uninstalling them.

These links might help

1. [How to remove extensions from Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/113907?hl=en)
2. [How to uninstall a program from windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/uninstall-change-program)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: 
Go to Settings
Scroll all the way down to "system" 
UNcheck "use hardware acceleration if available"

It does not work well in exactly your situation: Windows 8.1 + HD screen. I had the same problem and it was resolved.

Comment: Already tried this, no effect unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/RuTfbzaIQhA), and followed [these](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en) steps to create a new user profile, and problem has gone.

Comment: You might provide a short description of what the links say, links-only answers are not quality answers.